# Why shell script won't run when executed directly, but runs with /usr/bin/sh or /usr/bin/bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command, command-line-interface

Shell script file dummy.sh with -rw-r--r-- permission, runs fine with below commands.

```
/usr/bin/sh dummy.sh
```

(OR)

```
/usr/bin/bash dummy.sh
```

But ends up with **bash: ./dummy.sh: Permission denied** error, when executed directly as below. What's the reason behind this?

```
./dummy.sh
```

Comment: -rw-r-r is not enough for standalone execution. You need to set it as executable: `chmod 755 dummy.sh`

Comment: Becuase `dummy.sh` does not have execute permissions, where as `/usr/bin/sh` would be having executable permissions. do `ls -lrt /usr/bin/sh` to check the permission of `sh`. However `sh` is just a `symlink` to actualy shell, may be `bash`....

Answer (score 0):

Your Script needs to be marked as executable for your system. This is done by setting the "x" bit for either the owner, the group or the rest of the world.
See: [Wikipedia - Unix permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions)
By executing

```
chmod 755 dummy.sh
```

you will set read, write and execute permissions for the owner of the script and read and execute permissions for the group and the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Provide "execute" permission to your shell script, using either of the following options:

1. chmod 744 dummy.sh
2. chmod u+x dummy.sh

Do refer to [chmod documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)